# amqp - using autorecovery in case of broken connection

Tags: java, amqp

I am trying to use the autorecovery feature in case connection breaks.
I have 2 problems:

1) The autorecovery code seemingly completely ignores the networkRecoveryInterval. In my log file, for the 1 minute that the connection is broken, the file grows to 1.5 GB. The following error is constantly repeated.

> Caught an exception during connection recovery! 
>   java.net.SocketException: Network is unreachable  at
>   java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
>     at
>   java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
>     at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)   at
>   java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)  at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.FrameHandlerFactory.create(FrameHandlerFactory.java:32)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.newConnection(RecoveryAwareAMQConnectionFactory.java:34)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverConnection(AutorecoveringConnection.java:388)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.beginAutomaticRecovery(AutorecoveringConnection.java:360)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.access$000(AutorecoveringConnection.java:48)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection$1.shutdownCompleted(AutorecoveringConnection.java:345)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

2) Finally when I do switch my router on, the network recovery does not work. I get this in my log file.

> Caught an exception when recovering topology Caught an exception while
>   recovering queue 8923yrbk
>   com.rabbitmq.client.TopologyRecoveryException: Caught an exception
>   while recovering queue 8923yrbk   at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverQueues(AutorecoveringConnection.java:459)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverEntities(AutorecoveringConnection.java:424)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.beginAutomaticRecovery(AutorecoveringConnection.java:365)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.access$000(AutorecoveringConnection.java:48)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection$1.shutdownCompleted(AutorecoveringConnection.java:345)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ShutdownNotifierComponent.notifyListeners(ShutdownNotifierComponent.java:75)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQConnection$MainLoop.run(AMQConnection.java:572)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   com.rabbitmq.client.AlreadyClosedException: connection is already
>   closed due to connection error; cause:
>   com.rabbitmq.client.MissedHeartbeatException: Heartbeat missing with
>   heartbeat = 45 seconds    at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.ensureIsOpen(AMQChannel.java:190)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.rpc(AMQChannel.java:223)     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.privateRpc(AMQChannel.java:209)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.AMQChannel.exnWrappingRpc(AMQChannel.java:118)
>     at com.rabbitmq.client.impl.ChannelN.queueDeclare(ChannelN.java:779)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringChannel.queueDeclare(AutorecoveringChannel.java:230)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.RecordedQueue.recover(RecordedQueue.java:36)
>     at
>   com.rabbitmq.client.impl.recovery.AutorecoveringConnection.recoverQueues(AutorecoveringConnection.java:448)
>     ... 7 more

Here is my rather simple consumer side code. Note that I write all the code in a new Thread because I don't want my constructor to block.

```
private ConnectionFactory factory = null;
private Connection connection = null;
private Channel channel = null;

private PaymentInfoFromGlobalServerConsumer() {
    new Thread(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            factory = new ConnectionFactory();
            try {
                factory.setUri(amqpServerUrl);
                factory.setAutomaticRecoveryEnabled(true);
                factory.setNetworkRecoveryInterval(30000); // In case of broken connection, try again every 30 seconds (hope this is correct understanding)
                factory.setRequestedHeartbeat(45); //Keep sending the heartbeat every 45 seconds to prevent any routers from considering the connection stale.
            } catch (KeyManagementException | NoSuchAlgorithmException | URISyntaxException e) {
                //Will never happen if configured properly
                logger.error(e);
                return;
            }

            try {
                connection = factory.newConnection();
                channel = connection.createChannel();
                //Create a durable queue (if not already present)
                channel.queueDeclare(merchantId, true, false, false, null);

                QueueingConsumer consumer = new QueueingConsumer(channel);
                channel.basicConsume(merchantId, false, consumer);

                while (true) {
                    QueueingConsumer.Delivery delivery = consumer.nextDelivery();
                    String billId = new String(delivery.getBody());

                    //TODO - Redeliveries are possible as per design
                    System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + billId + "'");
                    System.out.println(" [x] Done" );

                    channel.basicAck(delivery.getEnvelope().getDeliveryTag(), false);
                }               
            } catch (IOException | ConsumerCancelledException | InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                logger.error(e);
            } catch (ShutdownSignalException e) {
                System.out.println(e.isInitiatedByApplication() + " " + e.isHardError());
            } finally {
                close();
            }
        }           
    }).start();
}

public void close() {
    try {
        if (channel != null) channel.close();
    } catch (IOException | AlreadyClosedException e) {
        //Cannot do anything now
    }
    try {
        if (connection != null) connection.close();
    } catch (IOException | AlreadyClosedException e) {
        //Cannot do anything now
    }
}
```

I am a newbie to amqp, so any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Try to recover the topology along with the connection.

```
factory.setTopologyRecoveryEnabled(true);
```

Comment: It enabled by default